# Как настроить строку подключения к MSSQL?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Проект использует EntityFramework Code First.

Строка подключения задана в отдельном классе:

```
public class ConnectionStrings
{
   public static readonly string connstr = @"Server=PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=ApacheServerLog;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";

}
```

Конструктор контекста :

```
public LogDataContext(string constr)
        : base(constr)
{

    Database.SetInitializer(new System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<LogDataContext>());
}
```

Создание экземпляра контекста:

```
public LogDataRepository()
{
    DB = new LogDataContext(ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.connstr);
}
```

У меня на машине все работает.
У работодателя (это тестовое задание) - исключение `Error 26: error locating server/instance specified`

Вопрос: Можно ли как-то настроить универсальную строку подключения, которая будет работать на всех машинах с MSSQL?

Comment: Ну вот например такого рода проблема: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/944390/fix-error-message-when-you-connect-to-a-named-instance-of-sql-server-o ... из которой следует, что надо аккуратнее относиться к указанию инстанса и максимально точно его определять - и то не всегда помогает...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Можно ли как-то настроить универсальную строку подключения, которая будет работать на всех машинах с MSSQL

Нельзя. MSSQL умеет устанавливатся в систему под разными именами экземпляров (instance), и настройки имени экземпляра по умолчанию у Express Edition (`имя-машины\SQLEXPRESS`, или `.\SQLEXPRESS`) отличаются от настройки имени экземлпяра у не-Express Edition (безымянный экземпляр, `имя-машины`, `.`).

Можно попробовать построить connection string поиском локальных экземпляров

- Подключить Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
- Вызвать [`SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms210334.aspx)
- Попытаться подключится к каждому из них с использованием `Trusted_Connection=True`.

Но этот способ сработает только в случае, если у текущего пользователя будет доступ у установленному экземпляру, так что результат не гарантирован.

Comment: Это нужно делать в файле ConnectionString.cs или app.config  Или в конструкторе DataContext? И, если можно, ссылку на пример кода.

Comment: @foxhound в  app.config вы точно код не напишете, так что где-то в  ConnectionString.cs